# Implementing certain functionality in the following program (OOP)

Tags: java

If two adjacent names are the same, but not the numbers, print a message to that effect, but still print out the data for the second entry.
If two adjacent entries are the same (name AND number), print out a duplicate error message (as in the previous classes). Keep track of the number of entries processed.

I need help implementing the above. I have the `PhoneNumber` as well as the `Name` class. Below is my code:

```
private Name name;
private PhoneNumber phonenumber;    

public PhonebookEntry(Name name, PhoneNumber phonenumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber; 
}

public void call() {
    System.out.println("Dialing "+ name.getFormal()+ ": ("+phonenumber.getAreaCode() +")"
    + phonenumber.getExchange()+"-" + phonenumber.getLineNumber());
    System.out.println();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File myFile = new File("phonebook.text"); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);

    int count =0;

    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
         Name name = new Name(scanner.next(), scanner.next());
         PhoneNumber phonenumber = new PhoneNumber(scanner.next());
         PhonebookEntry entry = new PhonebookEntry(name,phonenumber);
         count++;
         System.out.println( "phone book entry: "+name + ": "+ phonenumber);

        entry.call();
    }

    System.out.println( count+" phonebook entries processed.");
}
```

That's what I have thus far.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement equals() for all your entities - Name, PhoneNumber, PhonebookEntry. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/
2. Track a previous PhonebookEntry:
   eg.,

   ```
   PhonbookEntry prevEntry = null;
   while(scanner.hasNext()) {
       Name name = new Name(scanner.next(), scanner.next());
       PhoneNumber phonenumber = new PhoneNumber(scanner.next());
       PhonebookEntry entry = new PhonebookEntry(name,phonenumber);
       if(prevEntry != null){
           if(prevEntry.equals(entry)) // Exact same entry
               //print out error message
           else if(prevEntry.name.equals(entry.name) && !prevEntry.phoneNumber.equals(entry.phoneNumber))
               // print out the data
       }
       count++;
       System.out.println( "phone book entry: "+name + ": "+ phonenumber);}
       prevEntry = entry;
   ```

   }

Hope this helps